# Getting all scroll updates from a Recyclerview without breaking recycling

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I need my `Recyclerview` to work like a `ListView` with regards to scrolling so i can reposition other views on the screen when the list is scrolled. With a `ListView` i can just set an `OnScrollListener` which will call `onScroll` whenever the scroll position updates, which works fine when I need to reposition other views depending on how far my list has been scrolled.

However getting these Updates in a `Recyclerview` with a `LinearLayoutManager` has proven to be difficult for me. The `OnScrollListener` for `RecyclerView` does not update whenever the scroll position changes but only when the current behavior changes and when scrolling is completed. (`onScrolLStateChanged` and `onScrolled`).

So far the only solution I could find was wrapping my `RecyclerView` inside of a `NestedScrollView` and setting an `OnScrollListener` on that `NestedScrollView`. This, however, breaks recycling and is not a viable option because it leads to very poor performance.

Are there any alternative solutions to this problem that I missed, or am I just stuck with using `ListView`s if I want to achieve this for now?

Edit: I know about `setOnScrollChangeListener` for `RecyclerView` but it is only available for API 23 or higher. I need a version that is backward compatible down to API 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            Log.i("testscroll", "onScrolled: ");
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        }
    });
```

should notify every time a scroll occurs.

Comment: This will only be called after scrolling is completed. I need constant updates during scrolling too. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener

Comment: Dude, have you tested this? I did, and I receive constant updates even during the scroll. Check that out on your code and let me know.

Comment: Dang, youre right i was misled by the documentation. Thanks, you just saved me

Comment: Yeah, That's why sometimes I just jump right into code instead of reading documentation xD